# Using boolean to check model listview state android

Tags: android, checkbox, logic, android-recyclerview

I am working saving the current state of a check item while scrolling, and it worked, but i couldn't save the state of the TextView nothing the count when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

The code works fine, except that i could not save the state of holder.tvNewsCountLike while scrolling

(UPDATED)
this is my Adapter:

**NewsAdapter.java**

```
    public class TestNewsAdapter extends RealmBaseRecyclerViewAdapter<NewsTrend, TestNewsAdapter.PostsViewHolder> {

public RealmResults<NewsTrend> realmResults;
public Context context;
public EventListener eventListener;
static  String fbid;
private User user;


private RetrofitInterface restApi;

ArrayList<Boolean> positionArray;

boolean isFav;



public TestNewsAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<NewsTrend> realmResults,
                       boolean automaticUpdate, User user) {
    super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
    this.realmResults = realmResults;
    this.context = context;
    this.user = user;

    positionArray = new  ArrayList<>(realmResults.size());
    for(int i =0;i<realmResults.size();i++){
        positionArray.add(false);
    }
}

public void setEventListener(EventListener eventListener) {
    this.eventListener = eventListener;
}

@Override
public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    fbid = user.getId();
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_news, viewGroup, false);
    PostsViewHolder mediaViewHolder = new PostsViewHolder(v);
    return mediaViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PostsViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final NewsTrend postsData = getItem(position);

    holder.itemView.setTag(postsData);

    if (position % 2 == 1) {
        holder.llLeft.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        holder.llRight.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        holder.ivArrowLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.ivArrowRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    String eventName = postsData.getTitle();
    String eventDate = postsData.getTimestamp();
    holder.sourceName.setText(postsData.getType());
    Spanned decodedTitle = Html.fromHtml(eventName);

    holder.tvCountPageView.setText(postsData.getRead_count() + " Views");
    holder.tvNewsCountLike.setText(""+ postsData.getLike_count());

    holder.tvNewsTitle.setText(decodedTitle);
    holder.tvNewsDate.setText(getSplitDate(eventDate));
    String text = postsData.getContent() + "<font color='red'>  <strong>More...</strong></font>";
    holder.tvNewsShortText.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    if (postsData.getType().equals("Bella Naija")) {
        holder.sourceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bella);
    } else if (postsData.getType().equals("Punch")) {
        holder.sourceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.punch);
    } else if (postsData.getType().equals("Linda Ikeji")) {
        holder.sourceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.lib);
    } else if (postsData.getType().equals("Pulse")) {
        holder.sourceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.pulse_logo);
    }
    // holder.sourceName.setText(postsData.getType());

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(postsData.getImage())
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.tw_logo)
            .into(holder.ivNewsImage);



    if (postsData.getLike_status() == 1) {
        holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.kalp_dolu_kucuk);
    } else {
        holder.ivLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.kalp_bos_kucuk);
    }


    if (postsData.getArch_status() == 1) {
        Log.d("logFavourite", String.valueOf(postsData.getLike_status()));
        holder.ivFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.yildiz_dolu_kucuk);
        this.isFav = true;
    } else {
        holder.ivFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.yildiz_bos_kucuk);
        this.isFav = false;
    }

    holder.llRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            eventListener.onItemClick(v, postsData);
        }
    });


    holder.ivShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String shareBody = postsData.getHref();

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Trending App");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Paylaş"));
        }
    });

    holder.ivFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            eventListener.onFavClick(v,postsData,holder.ivFavorite, isFav);
        }
    });

    //holder.ivLike.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));

    holder.ivLike.setOnCheckStateChangeListener(new ShineButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(View view, boolean checked) {
            if (checked) {
                like(postsData.getNews_id());
                holder.tvNewsCountLike.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(holder.tvNewsCountLike.getText().toString()) + 1));
                positionArray.set(position, true);
            } else {
                like(postsData.getNews_id());
                holder.tvNewsCountLike.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(holder.tvNewsCountLike.getText().toString()) - 1));
                positionArray.set(position, false);
            }
        }
    });
}




@Override
public NewsTrend getItem(int i) {
    return realmResults.get(i);
}

public void swapData(RealmResults<NewsTrend> realmResults) {
    this.realmResults = realmResults;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return realmResults.size();
}

public static class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public RobotoTextView tvNewsDate;
    public RobotoTextView tvNewsTitle;
    public RobotoTextView tvNewsShortText;
    public RobotoTextView sourceName;
    public ImageView sourceImg;

    RelativeLayout postContentHolder;



    public LinearLayout llLeft;
    public LinearLayout llRight;

    public ImageView ivArrowLeft;
    public ImageView ivArrowRight;

    public ImageView ivNewsImage;

    public ImageView ivShare;

    public ImageView ivFavorite;
    public ShineButton ivLike;

    public TextView tvCountPageView;
    public TextView tvNewsCountLike;

    PostsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        postContentHolder = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postContentHolder);
        ivNewsImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivNewsImage);
        ivArrowLeft = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivArrowLeft);
        ivArrowRight = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivArrowRight);
        llLeft = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.llLeft);
        llRight = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.llRight);

        ivShare = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivShare);
        sourceImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sourceImg);
        sourceName = (RobotoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sourceName);
        tvNewsTitle = (RobotoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNewsTitle);
        tvNewsShortText = (RobotoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNewsShortText);
        tvNewsDate = (RobotoTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNewsDate);

        ivFavorite = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFavorite);
        ivLike = (ShineButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivLike);

        tvNewsCountLike = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNewsCountLike);
        tvCountPageView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCountPageView);

        ivLike.setOnCheckStateChangeListener(null);


    }
}

public interface EventListener {
    void onItemClick(final View view, NewsTrend postsData);

    void onLikeClick(final View view, NewsTrend postsDAta, TextView tvNewsCountLike,
                     ImageView ivLike, boolean check);

    void onFavClick(final View view, NewsTrend postData, ImageView ivArchive, boolean isArchive);

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

public String getSplitDate(String dateString){

    return dateString;
}



private void like(final int newsItemId) {
    setupRestClient();
    Log.e("logfb", "hunk" + fbid);
    restApi.like(newsItemId, fbid, new Callback<ReadStatus>() {
        @Override
        public void success(ReadStatus readStatus, Response response) {
            Log.e("logLike", "liked, id:" + newsItemId);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e("logLike", "fail like");

        }
    });

}

private void sendReadInfo(int id, String ext_date) {
    setupRestClient();

    restApi.sendReadInfo(id, fbid, ext_date, new Callback<ReadStatus>() {
        @Override
        public void success(ReadStatus readStatus, Response response) {
            Log.d("logRead", "Send info send: " + readStatus.isSuccess());

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d("logRead", "Send info failed");

        }
    });
}

private void unlike(final int newsItemId) {
    setupRestClient();

    restApi.unlike(newsItemId, fbid, new Callback<ReadStatus>() {
        @Override
        public void success(ReadStatus readStatus, Response response) {
            Log.e("logLike", "unliked, id:" + newsItemId);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e("logLike", "fail unlike");
        }
    });

}

private void archive(final int newsItemId, String ext_date){
    setupRestClient();

    restApi.sendArchiveInfo(newsItemId, fbid, ext_date, new Callback<ReadStatus>() {
        @Override
        public void success(ReadStatus readStatus, Response response) {
            Log.e("logArchive", "archive id:" + newsItemId);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e("logArchive", "fail archive");
        }
    });
}

private  void unArchive(final  int newsItemId){
    setupRestClient();

    restApi.sendUnArchiveInfo(newsItemId, fbid, new Callback<ReadStatus>() {
        @Override
        public void success(ReadStatus readStatus, Response response) {
            Log.e("logUnArchive", "archive id:" + newsItemId);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e("logUnArchive", "fail unArchive");
        }
    });
}


private void setupRestClient() {
    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://voice.atp-sevas.com")
            .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);

    RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();

    restApi = restAdapter.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
}
```

}

Comment: Is your code running successfully at least? I see you call `holder.ivLike` but in your declaration of the `PostsViewHolder` does not include `ivLike`. Please also confirm that the `setOnCheckStateChangeListener` does get called - for instance add a log statement to indicate that it is called.

Comment: Let me update and sent the full adapter, I tried to shorten it to avoid complexity

Comment: Good idea - as long as the question is clear - and where you have errors, you need to include these as well.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla the adapter is updated